# How to solve a limit through rationalizing but the radicand is a linear relation and the denominator is a quadratic?

Tags: calculus, limits, radical-equations

The question is :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sqrt {3x+4}-6}{x^2}}$$

My friend and I are absolutely stumped and can only attempt to solve through substitution. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use that $lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$ and the same for $lim_{x\rightarrow 0-}$?

Comment: And what happens to the numerator and denominator when you substitute $x=0$?

Comment: @RobertShore  what do you mean exactly? If you substitute x=0, then the answer is undefined.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I fixed with MathJax as suggested.

Comment: @babemcnuggets This is only my first unit of calculus so we haven't discussed anything like that yet.

Comment: It diverges to -oo because the numerator goes to -4 and the denominator is never negative.

Comment: @WilliamElliot You mean -4

Comment: @A.Hauser Well you must have had product rule, because I don't know another way to solve it without it, or am I wrong?

Comment: @babemcnuggets My teacher has given us the rules but we haven't done anything with them in class or in our textbook, so I don't understand how they are even supposed to be used yet

Comment: @babemcnuggets We've had all sorts of limit questions but none with an x^2 on the bottom, just x's

Comment: @WilliamElliot Okay that kinda makes sense, thanks I think!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For small x, -6 < $\sqrt {3x+4}$ - 6 < -1.
Since x$^2$ is positive, for small x
-6/x$^2$ < ($\sqrt {3x+4}$ - 6)/x$^2$ < -1/x$^2$.

As x approaches 0, the left hand and the right hand sides approach minus infinity, thus forcing the middle to 
approach minus infinity.

Answer (score -1):

At the limit,
the numerator is non-zero and negative
and the denominator is zero.

What does that tell you?

Comment: I have no idea.